# Determine the reason why onPause was invoked

Tags: android, onpause

I'm creating an app in which I need to make a certain action if the application was paused because the screen was turned off on its own due to lack of activity of the user with the device, and another action if the user had moved the application to the background on his own (for example by pressing the home button).

So is there a way to know why was `onPause` called? Or any other way which doesn't involve using `onPause`?

Comment: You should become intimately familiar with the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: @AlLelopath It does not answer my question which is about the life cycle itself

Comment: this is not about activity lifecycle!!! So what you need is a State Machine. You should declare like 3 states and in onPause you should check which state was called by handling the appropriate callbacks.

Comment: @matrix could you write an answer with a code example? The problem is how to know why the application is in a state of paused meaning determining the appropriate state?

Comment: @YonatanNir you can make it maunally by tracking number of activities in the stack and number of activities `onStop` and `onPause` .. hence from there you can ensure that application currently is in background

Comment: @MohamedFadelBuffon how will this answer let me know the reason why the on paused was invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few methods that you can hook into to see if there was a user interaction prior to onPause (onUserInteraction, onUserLeaveHint).

[Here](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle) is a good diagram on some of the lesser known lifecycle methods.

Comment: And which one of them can tell me the reason for the on pause invocation? Could you write a code example?

Comment: onUserLeaveHint() - and onUserInteraction() can be used for this
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()

The documentation indicates that you can capture events when there is interaction, and you can verify if onPause is called after this method or not.

```For example, when the user presses the Home key, onUserLeaveHint() will be called, but when an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity to be automatically brought to the foreground, onUserLeaveHint() will not be called on the activity being interrupted.```

Comment: Seems like onUserLeaveHint is whats needed here